# Why does convergence of $\Gamma(x)$ imply convergence of $\Gamma(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

A while ago I asked a question (link at the bottom) about the gamma function. It was answered with:

'$\int\limits_a^b e^{-t} t^{x-1}dt=\int\limits_a^b |e^{-t} t^{z-1}|dt$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}_{\Re(z)>0}$. Since the LHS converges, we have that $\int\limits_a^b e^t t^{z-1} dt$ converges.'

Why can we draw this conclusion? In my mind we can only draw conclusions about $\int|f(z)|dt$ and **not** about $\int f(z) dt$.

.

.

Link: [Does convergence of $\Gamma(x)$ imply convergence of $\Gamma(z)$? Is it generalisable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007613/does-convergence-of-gammax-imply-convergence-of-gammaz-is-it-generali?noredirect=1#comment6207211_3007613)

Comment: If $\int_a^b|f(u)|\,du$ is finite (and $f$ measurable) then $\int_a^bf(u)\,du$ exists (and is finite).

Comment: @Did But if $b=\infty$, mayhaps $\int\limits_a^b f(u)du$ becomes finite yet not convergent. In context of the Gamma function: we expect to get $\int f = c\in\mathbb{C}$ and thus can write $c=re^{i\varphi}$. Can't it be that as we take the limit $b\to\infty$ we have that $|c|$ converges, but $\varphi$ does not which means that c becomes finite yet does not converge?

Comment: @Did I think I cannot express myself more clearly, but the idea is that the "answer" to the integral could converge to the line $d(0,z) = 10$, but not a specific point on this line. This due to the fact that $|c|=|re^{i\varphi}|=r$ converges but $c=re^{i\varphi}$ does not since $\varphi$ does not converge as $b\to\infty$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolutely improper integrability implies improper integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339215/absolutely-improper-integrability-implies-improper-integrability)